# SecAddSharedWebCredential silent error when storing shared safari credentials - failed app review

Tags: ios, swift, security, secsharedcredentials

My app is failing review due to a hang on the login screen. When the user logs in, after the app receives a successful response it tries to store or update the user shared web credential.

The app has been reviewed and rejected by apple, they say the app hangs with the loading spinner on the screen, a state which I cannot reproduce and shouldn't be possible due to handling timeouts, successful, unsuccessful, or unrecognised http response codes.

```
@IBAction func pressedLogin(_ sender: UIButton) {
    OurCustomSpinner.sharedInstance.showSpinner()
    let loginOperation = LoginOperation(email: emailTextField.text!, password: passwordTextField.text!)

    loginOperation.success = { userItem in
        DispatchQueue.main.sync {
            // Try to store credentials, we don't care if it succeeds or fails, user should still go to next screen
            SecAddSharedWebCredential("midrive.com" as CFString, self.emailTextField.text! as CFString, self.passwordTextField.text! as CFString, { (error) in
                // Store user object (would crash if it failed)

                DispatchQueue.main.sync {
                    // Spinner hidden here - line never reached
                    OurCustomSpinner.sharedInstance.hideSpinner()
                    // Take user to next screen
                }
            })
        }
    }

    loginOperation.failure = { error in
        DispatchQueue.main.sync {
            // Spinner hidden here - line never reached
            OurCustomSpinner.sharedInstance.hideSpinner()
            self.presentError(message: error.localizedDescription)
        }
    }

    NetworkQueue.shared.addOperation(op: loginOperation)
}
```

As the app never reaches a place where the spinner is hidden, I can only think that the web request succeeds (hence no timeout error), and `SecAddSharedWebCredential` is somehow failing silently, possibly due to a security configuration on the devices used for app review.

Has anyone come across this before, or does anyone have any idea if there are security options that block shared web credentials? It works locally and prefills/updates passwords correctly, and works for our testflight users.

Just to update this, I resubmitted this without the `SecAddSharedWebCredential` line and it passed review first time.

Comment: Similar issue here.   Did you ever figure anything out?

Comment: I'm afraid not. In the end we left it out.